# Запятая по ситуации?

Tags: пунктуация

Приехать на 2 часа ,чтобы опять  не выспаться()и уехать за два часа до начала  из-за боязни опоздать?

Здравствуйте.
Запятая здесь ставится в зависимости от трактовки предложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Именно так.

Приехать на 2 часа ,чтобы опять не выспаться,и уехать за два часа до начала из-за боязни опоздать?-сложноподчинённое с одним придаточным.Приехать,(чтобы), и уехать ...?

Приехать на 2 часа ,чтобы опять не выспаться и уехать за два часа до начала из-за боязни опоздать?-сложноподч. с двумя однородными придаточными.Приехать, (чтобы не выспаться и уехать ...)?